# Can Step Function handle 500 execution per second?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Can Step Function handle around 500-1000 execution per second?

There will be around 500-1000 API calls per second to a Lambda function which then execute a Step Function.

Comment: take a look at aws documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State Transitioning Limit is related to what you are trying to do. Each Lambda execution counts as at least one StateTransition. It depends on your state machine.

For example if you have a wait state after Task State (Lambda) then you have two StateTransitions for each lambda call.
So here is the StateTransition Qutas:

| Service Metric | Bucket Size | Refill Rate per Second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| StateTransition — In US East (N. Virginia), US West (Oregon), and Europe (Ireland) | 5,000 | 1,500 |
| StateTransition — All other regions | 800 | 500 |

Update1: As `I'll-Be-Back` mentioned in the comment, if you are executing 1 Lambda per state machine, then you should consider StartExecution limits too:

| Service Metric | Bucket Size | Refill Rate per Second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| StartExecution — In US East (N. Virginia), US West (Oregon), and Europe (Ireland) | 1,300 | 300 |
| All Other Regions | 800 | 150 |

Thses limits are soft limits, so if that `Refill Rate` is not enough then use the Support Center page in the AWS Management Console to request a quota increase for resources provided by AWS Step Functions on a per-Region basis.

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html#service-limits-api-state-throttling

Update 2: Express State Machine has different limits.

Comment: I don't think you have considered StartExecution limit? 500-1000 per second to execute a new Step Function.

Comment: You have a point but usually we are executing more than one Lambda per state machine execution.